# Program freezing on run

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a program that works as a "math help calculator" and it asks you questions. I have a button on the calculator to ask you a new question and I want to be able to ask a maximum of ten questions. So I figured why not make a for loop where the button to ask a new questions makes the increment which will then prompt the new question. PROBLEM: for some reason unless I make it i++ in the for loop it's self. My program freezes. No syntax or run time errors but the java program freezes. I guess in theory it would work but I am doing something wrong?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10;){
if(e.getSource() == cmdNew){ 
i++;
}
```

Comment: What if they are not equal?

Comment: Then it stays one the current question being asked?

Comment: Your `i++` seems to be inside the `if` block. If you never go into the `if` block, `i` will stay at `0` and the `i<10` will never become `false`.

Comment: But I think that is the way I want it, if it does not increment, the current question will remain on the program and the when it increments a new one appears. So I want to to remain false until I hit the button for a new question?

Comment: The loop loops forever and blocks your program. You definitely do not want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your increment is in the incorrect place.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(e.getSource() == cmdNew) {

    } 
}
```

Comment: But with that, then the loop all happens at once even before hitting the button?

Comment: That means your if statement is never entered. Meaning e.getSource() is never the same as cmdNew

Comment: Thank you , I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are in an infinite loop. `(e.getSource() == cmdNew)` is never true so i never gets incremented and you just loop forever.

Comment: But with the code I have, wouldn't it make to so when you click the button assigned to cmdNew, it would increment i by one?

Comment: It would appear not, right?  You are not showing the definition of `e` or `cmdNew`, so it will be hard to tell if it is correct or not, but I'm pretty sure it is never true or your loop would terminate.